# Laravel Image intervention showing me Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object Laravel

Tags: laravel, image-processing, dropzone.js

I am using Laravel [Image Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel) Package with drop-zone plugin. And for sure I have installed it properly. When I try to upload images and then submit the form its showing me the following error message 
 
**"Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object"**

Even this error message showing me if i blank this input field form. In that case it is expected to me  not showing me any error message as it is not mandatory field to submit the form But it did.

I have two query.

1) what's going wrong in my code 
2) Right now I am trying to upload single image. For multiple images I want to store the files info as an array. In that case what would my code in controller.

Here is my live link you can check from here 
http://thetoppinghouse.com/laravel/public/admin/index/create 
http://laravel.io/bin/Jxmzo

Here is my controller code

```
public function store()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Index::$rules);
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

        if ($validator->passes()) {
            $index = new Index;
            $index->name = Input::get('name');
            $index->category_ID = Input::get('category_ID');

            $files = Input::file('files');
            $filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s')."-".$files->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = public_path('img/index/' . $filename);
            Image::make($files->getRealPath())->save($path);
            $index->files = 'img/index/'.$filename;
            $index->save();

            return Redirect::route('admin.index.index')->with('message', 'Index Created');

        }

    }
```

// Form Code

```
<ul class="post-list">
     <li>
         {{ Form::label('parent_ID', 'Category') }}
         {{ Form::select('parent_ID',Category::lists('category_name','id'),Input::old('category'),array('class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id' => 'parent_ID')) }}
      </li>

       <li>
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Index Name') }}
        {{ Form::text('name', null, array( 'class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Name' )) }}
        {{ $errors->first('name', '<p class="error">:message</p>' ) }}
      </li>


        <li>
          {{ Form::label('image', 'Cover Image') }}
        </li>

           <div class="dropzone" id="DropzoneArea">
                <div class="fallback">
                   <input name="files" type="file" id="files" multiple>
                </div>
            </div>

          {{ Form::submit('Save') }}
        </li>
</ul
```

Comment: is `Input::file('files');` returns `null` ?

Comment: yes ................

Comment: thats because, when u try to upload with dropzone it will automatically uload the image into the server, so your file input has nothing. can u please put some code how u handle the image upload in laravel with dropzonejs ?

Comment: I just add this line. Rest of the things done by Dropzone <br />

$("div#DropzoneArea").dropzone({ url: '/' });

Answer (score 1):

handle the file upload with dropzone like,

```
 var fileDropzone = new Dropzone("div#DropzoneArea", {
    url: '/upload',          // customize the URL
    addRemoveLinks: false
 });
```

then when u uploading something upload action will call and u can handle the file upload in that action. then you can return the server file path of uploaded file.

```
 fileDropzone.on("success", function (file,data,e) {
    var hiddenInput = $('<input name="filePath" type="hidden value=" '+ data.path +' "">');
    // and append the hiddenInput in to the form
 });
```

then after success upload you can set the server path of the uploaded file in a input `hidden field`. after you submit the form you can get the file by hidden field value.

when you submit the form, get uploaded file as,

```
$filePath = Input::input('filePath');
$file = File::get($filePath);
```